# Are empty for loops in PHP considered bad practice?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm currently writing a bit of code to shift the values of an associative array to the right in PHP 7.0, and have used a for loop with no instructions in it:

```
$array = array("one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3, "four" => 4);
$first = reset($array);
$last = end($array);

for (end($array); current($array) !== $first && key($array) !== null; $array[key($array)] = prev($array)){
    continue;
}
$array[key($array)] = $last;
```

The code works and outputs what I need, but I can't help but feel like there's something wrong with such a structure. Maybe there's a clearer way of doing it? (I'm asking myself this primarily because my code will not be maintained by me in the future, and I want it to be as clean as possible)

I couldn't find anything on the subject on the manual page or on blogs. Is it generally frowned upon or more up to one's own opinion?

Comment: @RiggsFolly — The question is about best practice, not validity.

Comment: @Quentin And my answer was `No!` even though best practice is not really on topic

Comment: It's definitely not very readable.  Use documentation at the very least.

Comment: _“code will not be maintained by me in the future, and I want it to be as clean as possible”_ - then you should probably rather not use such constructs (at least not without very clear documentation.) A while loop would probably be more readable to most developers.

Comment: Why loop if there are no instructions?

Comment: This is definitely not intuitive to read. Have you tried rewriting your loop as a `while` or `do while`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll say its bad practice, because even though it's valid, I find from experience that refactoring it into a while loop almost always makes it more readable.

```
$array = array("one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3, "four" => 4);
$first = reset($array);
$last = end($array);

while (current($array) !== $first && key($array) !== null) {
    $array[key($array)] = prev($array);
}

$array[key($array)] = $last;
```

Comment: The last line from the question is missing, otherwise this works fine: https://3v4l.org/2gNCs

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In my rush I forgot about the good ol' while loop, which is definitely a cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion for a different approach that may be a little easier to read than a loop.

```
// save the keys
$keys = array_keys($array);
// shift the values right
array_unshift($array, array_pop($array));
// restore the keys
$array = array_combine($keys, $array);
```

As far as your concern for whoever will be maintaining the project in the future, whether it's you or someone else, you should try to write the code in such a way that it is obvious what each part is supposed to do. One easy way to do that:

```
function shift_values_right(array $array) {  // code that does that }
```

I'd prefer this over an explanatory comment if I inherited the project.